# Removing row in df1 if pair of column values aren't paired in another df2

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, filter, group-by

Given df1 and df2, I want to get df3. The only columns/rows I want to match are *Pop* and *Homes*. I've included the *Other* column of data to get a solution for an arbitary amount of columns.

```
df1
City        Pop  Homes Other
City_1      100      1     0
City_1      100      2     6
City_1      100      2     2
City_1      100      3     9
City_1      200      1     6
City_1      200      2     6
City_1      200      3     7
City_1      300      1     0

df2
City        Pop  Homes Other
City_1      100      1     0
City_1      100      2     6
City_1      100      2     2
City_1      100      8     9
City_1      200      1     6
City_1      200      2     6
City_1      800      3     7
City_1      800      8     0

df3
City        Pop  Homes Other
City_1      100      1     0
City_1      100      2     6
City_1      100      2     2
City_1      200      1     6
City_1      200      2     6
```

I thought about grouping by City, Pop, and Homes, like df1.groupby(['City', 'Pop', 'Homes']), but then I don't know how to filter out the inequalities of *Pop* and *Homes*.

**EDIT**

Here is my code so you can help me easier.

```
df1_string = """City_1      100      1     0
City_1      100      2     6
City_1      100      2     2
City_1      100      3     9
City_1      200      1     6
City_1      200      2     6
City_1      200      3     7
City_1      300      1     0"""

df2_string = """City_1      100      1     0
City_1      100      2     6
City_1      100      2     2
City_1      100      8     9
City_1      200      1     6
City_1      200      2     6
City_1      800      3     7
City_1      800      8     0"""

df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.split() for x in df1_string.split('\n')], columns=['City', 'Pop', 'Homes', 'Other'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([x.split() for x in df2_string.split('\n')], columns=['City', 'Pop', 'Homes', 'Other'])

df1_keys = [x for x in df1.groupby(['Pop', 'Homes']).groups.keys()]
df2_keys = [x for x in df2.groupby(['Pop', 'Homes']).groups.keys()]

print(df1_keys)
[('100', '1'), ('100', '2'), ('100', '3'), ('200', '1'), ('200', '2'), ('200', '3'), ('300', '1')]
print(df2_keys)
[('100', '1'), ('100', '2'), ('100', '8'), ('200', '1'), ('200', '2'), ('800', '3'), ('800', '8')]
```

From here is would seem simple to filter out the group pairs which are not equal, but I can't solve this. I've tried:

```
df1 = df1[df1.groupby(['Pop', 'Homes']).groups.keys().isin(df2.groupby(['Pop', 'Homes']).groups.keys())]
```

And other variations of this when it didn't work - but I have a feeling it's close to working.

**SOLUTION**

```
df1.set_index(['Pop', 'Homes'], inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['Pop', 'Homes'], inplace=True)

df1 = df1[df2.index.isin(df1.index)]

df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Adding an [mcve] will significantly help those to provide a functioning answer.  But you've got good answers below.

Comment: @RichAndrews I've made an edit. It should be clearer now

Comment: Looks great.  Did you know people 'copy' the data to their computer clipboard and `pandas.read_clipboard()`?  Super convenient.    I think you had your code attempt in your Q too, no reason to exclude it. But you've got good answers to review!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC and if City, Pop, Home are in the index, then you can use `isin`:

```
df2[df2.index.isin(df1.index)]
```

Output:

```
                 Count
City  Pop Homes       
City1 100 20       152
          24       184
      200 41       163
          42       163
```

Comment: Do those df's refer to groupby objects like: df1.groupby(['City', 'Pop', 'Homes'])  and df2.groupby(['City', 'Pop', 'Homes']) ?

Comment: Yes.  That groupby should create that structure of index.

Comment: That doesn't work, I get an AttributeError: Cannot access attribute 'index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Answer (score 0):

Create multiindexes for the dataframes and do an inner join for the intersection.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df1_string = """City_1      100      1     0
City_1      100      2     6
City_1      100      2     2
City_1      100      3     9
City_1      200      1     6
City_1      200      2     6
City_1      200      3     7
City_1      300      1     0"""

df2_string = """City_1      100      1     0
City_1      100      2     6
City_1      100      2     2
City_1      100      8     9
City_1      200      1     6
City_1      200      2     6
City_1      800      3     7
City_1      800      8     0"""

df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.split() for x in df1_string.split('\n')], columns=['City', 'Pop', 'Homes', 'Other'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([x.split() for x in df2_string.split('\n')], columns=['City', 'Pop', 'Homes', 'Other'])

# Dataframes benefit from having indexes that reflect that tabular data
df1.set_index(['City', 'Pop', 'Homes'], inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['City', 'Pop', 'Homes'], inplace=True)

# an inner join on the multiindex will provide the intersaction of the two
result = df1.join(df2, how='inner', on=['City', 'Pop', 'Homes'], lsuffix='_l', rsuffix='_r')

# a join provides all of the joined columns
result.reset_index(inplace=True)
result.drop(['Other_r'], axis=1, inplace=True)
result.columns = ['City', 'Pop', 'Homes', 'Other']

print(result)
```